# Using promise to pass results of one NodeJS module.export function to another NodeJS module.export function

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm working in some existing NodeJS code with Core and CoreTest as two of the functions. CoreTest runs a query and stores the selected rows in a variable called CoreSQL. Core is also running some queries, however it requires part of CoreSQL as a parameter for one of the queries.

I think I'm calling CoreTest incorrectly

```
module.exports = {

    CoreTest: (req, res) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const core = db.format.escape(req.query.q);
            const coreSQL = `query with parameter = ${core}`;
            returnData(coreSQL, resolve, reject);
            resolve(coreSQL);
        })
    },

    Core: (req, res) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (req.query.q.length > 0) {
                var core = module.exports.CoreTest(req, res);
            }
            else
            {
                reject("PROBLEMS")
            }
            const coreSQLceDevID = `query where parameter like ${core}`
            const coreSQLpID = `query where parameter like ${coreSQLceDevID})`
            const coreSQL = `query where parameter like ${coreSQLpID}`
            returnDataB(coreSQL, resolve, reject);
        })
    } 
}
```

The return data functions run the SQL query and looks as follows:

```
const returnData = (sql, resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err)
            reject(err)
        else
            resolve(result)
    })
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: Unhandled rejection!
Reason:TypeError: Cannot read property 'q' of undefined,
Promise: [object Promise]
```

Although when I use breakpoints to check the value of q, its not undefined, so it must be an issue with how CoreTest is being called.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- in `CoreTest`, you are calling both `returnData` and `resolve`. Drop the immediate `resolve()` call, `returnData` will do that later. (Btw, I'd recommend renaming that to `runQuery` or so).

  ```
  CoreTest(req, res) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const core = db.format.escape(req.query.q);
          const coreSQL = `query with parameter = ${core}`;
          returnData(coreSQL, resolve, reject);
      })
  }
  ```
- in `Core`, you seem to expect `CoreTest()` to return a value synchronously. It can't do that, it returns a promise. You will need to chain the rest of your code to that with `then` or `await`. Also you should keep the `new Promise` wrapper minimal:

  ```
  Core(req, res) {
      if (req.query.q.length == 0) {
          return Promise.reject("PROBLEMS");
      }
      return module.exports.CoreTest(req, res).then(core => {
  //                                          ^^^^^
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const coreSQLceDevID = `query where parameter like ${core}`
              const coreSQLpID = `query where parameter like ${coreSQLceDevID})`
              const coreSQL = `query where parameter like ${coreSQLpID}`
              returnDataB(coreSQL, resolve, reject);
          });
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: I implemented the above changes but continue to get the same error

Comment: @Manaar Oh, I didn't check the error message. `Cannot read property 'q' of undefined` means that your request didn't contain a `query` parameter. About that you best [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you post the (express.js?) server code that calls `Core`.

Comment: @Manaar Also if you are getting an `Unhandled rejection!` that means you didn't add a rejection handler to the promise returned by the call. Use something like `.catch(err => { console.error(err); res.status(500); })` (or some more appropriate handling than 500, e.g 400 if the  `query` parameter is missing)